# Springboot - How to name response array and objects in a JSON response

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest

I have Springboot REST API application with controller like:

```
@GetMapping()
public List<CarResponse> getCars() {
    List<CarResponse> cars= carService.getCars();
    return cars;
}
```

My CarResponse looks like:

```
public class CarResponse {
    private int id;
    private String type;
    private String model;
}
```

This is working fine; however, returned JSON consist of an JSON anonymous array of anonymous JSON objects like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "SUV",
        "model": "Toyota"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "SPORT",
        "model": "Porsche"
    },
    ...
]
```

How do I get response consisting of named array and objects so the response JSON looks like

```
{
    "cars": [
            "car": {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "SUV",
                "model": "Toyota"
            },
            "car": {
                "id": 2,
                "type": "SPORT",
                "model": "Porsche"
            },
            ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your desired result is invalid JSON…

Comment: Start with defining an additional class for the wrapper object containing only the `List<CarResponse> cars`.

Comment: I get your point about 2nd comment, but about your 1st comment, are you saying I cannot have named "car" objects in the array?

Comment: I think you just missed some braces, verify with an online JSON validator.